# KafkaConsumer: what happen if committed is before beginningOffsets?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am debugging some kafka consuming app that is stuck. The app is running fine (up, no memory problem), but no message is processed.

It is not my code, so I'm discovering (most of) it. However I found in some logs that the committed offset (`KafkaConsumer.committed`) is before the first offset available in the kafka partition (`KafkaConsumer.beginningOffset`). For example, I have:

- committed = position = 8000
- beginningOffset = 740.000
- endOffsets = 760.000

We may have some bug in the way we commit offset (using `KafkaConsumer.commitSync`, and with `enable.auto.commit` false). But this is not the question here.

However looking into the kafka code, I cannot understand what should happened in such a case, when polling messages. Will it send nothing, messages starting at beginningOffset, fails, ... ?

Basically, is it a potential reason for the app to get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs), if you have an invalid offset like this, `auto.offset.reset` will kick in and will use the setting you've chosen (default is `latest`) to move your position to the appropriate place in the log.

The wording in the doc is as follows:

`auto.offset.reset: What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted)`

This seems to include the scenario you've described above.

Comment: So if `auto.offset.reset` is latest (I think it's our case), it won't do anything? That would be quite an easy way to stuck any consumer. I.e. as soon as it it late enough, it won't process anything behaving like it processed everything.

Comment: Yeah, it'll move to the latest position in the log and then only consume subsequent messages that are produced after that point in time. You could set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` to help mitigate this somewhat, but it depends on how accepting you are of duplicate messages.

Comment: I don't understand why it would start again when there is new msg. If the stored offset is invalid and using latest, consumer won't poll any msg, thus they won't update the stored offset. So the offset will stay invalid, and keep using latest in later poll, again and again. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes; as soon as the consumer polls and finds that the offset is invalid, the consumer will be reset to the latest offset. When it then polls again, the offset is no longer invalid, so it will not be reset again, and will instead start consuming from that point onward.

Comment: ok, so when it polls the stored offset is updated (which is logical actually).